# Validations for jQuery not fully working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I'm having an issue on where only part of my validation works and I can't seem to figure out where the problem is. In the page, I have validations for address, city, zip, and credit card, but the validations do not work for the credit card.

html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Billing Information</title>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    .error {
    background-color: #ffc;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table border='1'>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <form action="signin.html" id="signup">
      <p>
        <label for="name">Address:</label>
        <input type="text" name="address" id="address" />
      </p>

      <p>
        <label for="name">City: </label>
        <input type="text" name="city" id="city" />
      </p>

      <p>
        <label for="name">ZIP Code:</label>
        <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip" size='3'/>
      </p>

    </td>

    <td>
        <p><b>What is your preferred billing method?</b></p>

      <input type="radio" name="payment" id="ccard" value="cc" />
      <label for="cCard">Credit Card</label><br />

      <div id="cardInfo">
        <!-- doesn't work here -->
        <label for="name">Card Number: </label>
        <input type="text" name="cnum" id="cnum" size='15' /> <br />

        <label for="name">Expiration Date:</label>
        <input type="text" name="exp" id="exp" size='4' />
      </div>

    </td>
    <td>
      <p align='center'>
        <input type="submit" id='submit'>
      </p>
    </td>
    </form>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

js:

```
$(function() {

     // validations using plugin
   $('#signup').validate({
     rules: {
       address: 'required',
       city: 'required',
       zip: {
         required:true,
         digits:true,
         minlength:5,
         maxlength:5
       },
       cnum: 'required'
     }
   });  
});
```

EDIT: If I move card number over to the first column, the validations work but it doesnt when it is in the 2nd column

http://jsfiddle.net/JqSBC/

Comment: did you try `cardInfo: 'required'` than just `cnum: 'required'`?

Comment: tried but it doesnt work

Comment: see my answer. Also i would suggest you to put your code in www.jsfiddle.net to make it easier for others to debug

Comment: `cardInfo` is not a name of a form element... will do no good. Code above looks fine, what does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: If I leave the page empty and submit, only address,city, and zip shows the error messages, but credit card doesnt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the form element outside the table element.

A form is not allowed to be a child element of a table, tbody or tr.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your table with the form tags rather than having the form tag inside of the first td.

`#cardInfo` doesn't exist inside of `#signup` form in your original example, so it gets ignored.

Also, use the name/id of the input element rather than the container div.

http://jsfiddle.net/JqSBC/3/